# Play dependency injection reload

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, sbt

While developing a play framework (version 2.5.9) in Scala using the proposed dependency injection mechanism (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) using guice.

The application uses a custom module (published as jar and imported as external dependency) that has singleton classes (A,B) that uses other classes (1,2) injected with dependency injection mechanism.

The same injected classes (1,2) are used in the current application with the same method.

So for example:

Class A belonging to the custom module uses class 1 that is provided by dependency injection

Class C belonging to the application currently developed uses class 1 that is provided by dependency injection

This set up works fine until changes in the code during the development process triggers sbt to recompile and reload the application.

When this happens the application is restarted but the classes in the module are not provided with the new instances of injected classes (ex. 1) and so if for example class 1 is the database trait in play framework the instance provided in the module stop to work forcing the developer to restart the application from scratch.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening and having sbt/play "autoreload" the application in way that continue to work correctly.

I hope I've made my problem somehow clear :)

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking, but SBT doesn't automatically reload the build definition, which includes external dependencies, unless you ask it to by invoking `reload` command in console.

Comment: yes, probably i hasn't too clear but essentially my issue is that while developing a play application launching that with sbt run when the application is reloaded due to code changes the classes in the included module (which is included as external dependency in the build.sbt file) aren't provided with the new instances of the injected dependencies for that classes. i hope this make things a little more clear.